# Strange variables. XSL

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I've such piece of code:

```
<xsl:template match="bottom">
<div class="l1">
    <div class="l2">
        <div class="fl100">
            <div align="center">
                <div class="mw" align="center">
                    <div class="footer">
                        <div class="f1">$-BOTTOM_COPY-$</div>
                        <div class="f2">
                            $-BOTTOM_CONTACTS-$
                        </div>

                        <div class="f3">
                          $-BOTTOM_LINKS-$

                        </div>

                        <div class="f4">
                            $-BOTTOM_STUDY-$
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I cannot understan where from $-BOTTOM_CONTACTS-$, $-BOTTOM_LINKS-$ etc variables are.
I'm new in xsl, and searched every src files, but didn't find any declaration of define in php code.
Any idea?

Comment: It is not inherent to XSL. Either it is defined elsewhere in the XSL file, another XSL file is included into this one, or it is replaced by your code. It might also be that these fields are defined in a database your app might be running on. Anyway, I would do full text search again on your code to look for BOTTOM_CONTACTS, *not* $-BOTTOM_CONTACTS-$. Also check if it appears in a database.

Comment: Full text search didn't give the result. I'll try to search in database, but there is a problem: it's totally encrypted. Thanks.

Comment: XSL defines variables, as might other XML-based standards. http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/02/07/trxml9.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if someone has included these bits of text (like $-BOTTOM_STUDY-$) as a target for replacement with something specific. Either they intended them to be replaced in the stylesheet before running the transformation, or they intended them to be replaced in the output file after running the transformation. But as far as XSLT is concerned, they are just strings to be copied from the stylesheet to the result document.